# How CyanogenMod10 figures out caller's location?

Tags: android, android-4.2-jelly-bean, cyanogenmod

**Edit**: Changed JellyBean to cyanogenmod 10 as it's probably a cyanogen feature

I noticed my phone under CyanogenMod10 phone displays in the call log the (approximate) location of callers (only when the number is a land line phone not in my contacts).

It doesn't just rely on the country code because it also displays the city of the caller when found. I browsed the Contacts package app and found values was fetched from database (in com.android.contacts.CallDetailActivity)

```java
final String countryIso = callCursor.getString(COUNTRY_ISO_COLUMN_INDEX);
final String geocode = callCursor.getString(GEOCODED_LOCATION_COLUMN_INDEX);
```

So I though it was in the Phone package app after successfully placing or receiving a call. But I quickly lost myself in the source... I would to know where and (briefly) how those values are set and the geocode resolved.

Are phone numbers sent to a mysterious web service?

Does Cyanogen have a table with all country codes and city prefixes of the world (I doubt it)?

Or is that DB downloaded depending on the country you are in?

Comment: MIUI Roms had this feature long before Jelly Bean, but they didn't resolved down to the City.

Comment: actually i am using cyanogenmod10 I wondered before asking if it wasn't a Cyanogen feature instead :/ I dont have a google phone to compare, maybe i should edit my question...

Comment: Maybe its a Cyanogen feature. Use an app like [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.eolwral.osmonitor) to pin down if telephony service or contacts app connects to any server for location details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found how this thing work

First 
ContactsProvider add this value when calling DefaultCallLogInsertionHelper.addComputedValues

see here

https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_packages_providers_ContactsProvider/blob/ics/src/com/android/providers/contacts/DefaultCallLogInsertionHelper.java#L59

```
@Override
public void addComputedValues(ContentValues values) {
    // Insert the current country code, so we know the country the number belongs to.
    String countryIso = getCurrentCountryIso();
    values.put(Calls.COUNTRY_ISO, countryIso);
    // Insert the geocoded location, so that we do not need to compute it on the fly.
    values.put(Calls.GEOCODED_LOCATION,
            getGeocodedLocationFor(values.getAsString(Calls.NUMBER), countryIso));
}
```

so code you see

```
final String countryIso = callCursor.getString(COUNTRY_ISO_COLUMN_INDEX);
final String geocode = callCursor.getString(GEOCODED_LOCATION_COLUMN_INDEX);
```

is actually reading from saved data

So, real data are from PhoneNumberOfflineGeocoder which you can find here
https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_external_libphonenumber/blob/ics/java/src/com/android/i18n/phonenumbers/geocoding/PhoneNumberOfflineGeocoder.java

That is something called `libphonenumber`

https://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/

Comment: Great!! Everyone seems to care of Privacy but no one spotted this feature as potentially intrusive. Thank you :)